# Scrolling div by the #id, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, javascript

I'm programming a message board for my site. Every message gets an id by auto increment in the database. The messages on the board are under "li id=#" tags where the "li" gets the id from the database. I've tried to create scrolling function via javascript so that down and up arrows would move across whole messages.

This is what I've got so far:

```
down.node.onclick = function() { // down arrow

var msgs = document.getElementById("kommentit"); // the <ul> element
var a = new Array();


if (msgs.hasChildNodes()) {
    var children = msgs.childNodes;
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        if (msgs.childNodes[i].tagName == "LI") {
            a.push(msgs.childNodes[i].id); // array with the id's
        }
    }

}

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) { // this is what goes wrong
    parent.location.href = '#' + 'a[i + 1]';
}
```

So while the array gets the right values the actual function doesn't work. With this code I get .../index.php#[a + 1] as my url when I click.

If I use ''+a[i + 1]+'' the page refreshes through the whole array until it settles with #undefined.

The id's are in format "id-xx" so is that the problem? I tried splitting the id by using msgs.childNodes[i].id.split("id-") but if I do this I get ",xx" as my values in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want scroll to next item each time you have to track down the last item you scrolled to.
Not to invent the bicycle, I suggest you use some JS frameworks and plugins for scrolling. It will save you a lot of time.

Examples are:

- [jQuery](http://jquery.com) - framework
- [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/) - scrolling plugin

Answer (score 1):

try that

```
down.node.onclick = function() { // down arrow

var msgs = document.getElementById("kommentit"); // the <ul> element
var a = new Array();


if (msgs.hasChildNodes()) {
    var children = msgs.childNodes;
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        if (msgs.childNodes[i].tagName == "LI") {
            a.push(msgs.childNodes[i].id); // array with the id's
        }
    }

}

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) { // this is what goes wrong
    parent.location.href = '#' + a[i];
}
```

Comment: Same thing as ''+a[i + 1]+'', it goes through the whole array and then settles with #undefined. (and location goes to the last real value)

Comment: can you put an example on jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: http://pohjis.site40.net/testi.php you can find it there but only the DOWN arrow is functional

Comment: ok i found the problem. you for loop is from 0 to a.length. but with `a[i+1]` it is from 1 to a.length+1 and then you try to access a value which is not there, thats why its undefined. look at my solution for a fix

Answer (score 0):

Why are you adding 1 to the array index?

Have you tried:

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) { // this is what goes wrong
    parent.location.href = '#' + a[i];
}
```

But I'd probably use jquery (or similar) for something like this, as changing the url like the above adds loads of things into the user's history and breaks the back button.

Comment: Ah, yes again same deal as before so it scrolls through the whole thing. Thanks for your feedback too, I think I'm trying the jCarousel suggested before. Bit of a novice here, this is my first programming so learning a lot all the time.